# Polymer error "A type with that name is already registered" using Polymer.Base.importHref

Tags: javascript, polymer, custom-element, html-imports

I have a Polymer component that's referenced by other components. Something like:

In `index.html`

```
<link rel="import" href="lib/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="component-one.html">

...

<component-one></component-one>
```

In `component-one.html`

```
<link rel="import" href="sub-component.html">
<dom-module id="component-one">
    <template>
        <sub-component></sub-component>
    </template>
    <script>Polymer({ is: 'component-one' });</script>
</dom-module>
```

In `component-two.html`

```
<link rel="import" href="sub-component.html">
<dom-module id="component-two">
    <template>
        <sub-component></sub-component>
    </template>
    <script>Polymer({ is: 'component-two' });</script>
</dom-module>
```

In `sub-component.html`

```
<dom-module id="sub-component">
    <template>blah blah blah</template>
    <script>Polymer({ is: 'sub-component' });</script>
</dom-module>
```

The problem comes in when I attempt to dynamically load the second component in `index.html`:

```
function importHref(href) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Polymer.Base.importHref(href, function (e) {
            resolve(e.target);
        }, reject, true);
    });
}

...

await importHref('component-two.html');
// Now I can use <component-two>
```

This throws an exception:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'registerElement' on 'Document': Registration failed for type 'sub-component'. A type with that name is already registered.

I figure this is happening due to `sub-component.html` being referenced by two components, but both also reference lots of paper and iron elements and none of them cause this error.

How to I avoid this exception?

Comment: there's no problem. the issue should be somewhere else in you code.

Comment: @Supersharp Ah, yes, it is, I'll add an answer in case anyone else hits this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was a typo in the path to the sub-component.

In `component-one.html`

```
<link rel="import" href="../components//sub-component.html">
```

In `component-two.html`

```
<link rel="import" href="../components/sub-component.html">
```

Both of these successfully route (in IIS/Kestrel) and return `sub-component.html`, but are seen by Polymer as two different URI and hence two different components.

If you get this error double check that all your imports resolve to identical URIs, not just that they return the correct content.